# Compact Operator Inversion

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let I be a positive compact in $\mathscr{B}(\mathscr{H})$ *(where $\mathscr{H}$ is some Hilbert space)* then $I$ can be written (uniquely) as $A^2=I$ for some $A \in \mathscr{B}(\mathscr{H})$.

My question is: "is $A$ necessarily invertible?"

Answer (score 1):

If the Hilbert space is infinite dimensional, then $A$ is necessarily **non**-invertible, because if $A$ is invertible, so is $I$, but $I$ is compact and compact operators can not be invertible in Infinite dimensional Banach spaces.

If the Hilbert space is finite dimensional, then $I$ is injective (because it is positive), hence $A$ is also injective, hence bijective (for reasons of finite dimension), hence invertible.

Comment: Indeed but in physics some important self-adjoint operators have compact resolvent which has immediate consequences for their spectrum. In other cases such as Schrödinger operators of the type $H={H_0}+V$, $V$ times the resolvent of $H_0$ is compact. again having important spectral consequences. In summary compactness can play an important role even if the original operator is not compact.